# Have two or more tuples with the same attribute value

Tags: database, attributes, tuples

With SQL, can I have more than one tuple with the same value for all the attributes in the table? Are there any conflicts or problems here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for that!

The reason is **Primary key values Data Integrity Rule**.

> Primary key values: A primary key value rule defined on a key (a
>   column or set of columns) specifies that each row in the table can be
>   uniquely identified by the values in the key.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#CNCPT1623

Comment: I forgot I had a primary key on the table. Thank you for answering these questions.